# Sql: select only value that join table has value equal to 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables in mysql.

ADS

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

PAYMENTS

| id | ads_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 |

INSTALLMENTS

| id | Payment_id | paid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 1 |
| 6 | 4 | 0 |
| 7 | 4 | 1 |
| 8 | 5 | 0 |

I want to get count of ads that have only payments with all installments.paid = 1.

As an example, return value is 2 for ads.id = 1 (only payment.id 2 AND 3 has all installments.paid = 1) and 0 for ads.id = 0

I tried with

```
SELECT ads.id AS id, 
    (
    select count(*)
    from payments
    where 
        (SELECT count(*)
        FROM installments
        where (installments.payment_id = payments.id AND (installments.paid = 0))) <1 
            AND payments.ad_id = ads.id
    )
FROM ads 
LEFT JOIN payments ON ads.id = payments.ad_id 
LEFT JOIN installments ON installments.payment_id = payments.id
GROUP BY ads.id
```

But doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach this is using `group by` and `having`.  To get the ad ids, you don't actually need the ads table, because installments has this information:

```
select i.ads_id
from installments i join
     payments p
     on i.payment_id = p.id
group by i.ads_id
having min(i.paid) = 1 and min(i.paid) = max(i.paid);
```

Note that this is checking both the minimum and maximum value -- just in case some other value were to creep in.  If the value could be `NULL`, you would also want `and count(*) = count(i.paid)`.

Another approach to this would just use `not exists` or `not in`:

```
select a.*
from ads a
where not exists (select 1
                  from installments i join
                       payments p
                       on i.payment_id = p.id
                  where p.ads_id = a.id and i.paid <> 0
                 );
```